# How can I make this SSIS expression work?

Tags: ssis, expression

I am trying to set the data source as a dynamic variable, but i keep getting error. I wonder if anyone can help me correct my expression below. Thank you! This is an OLE DB data source connection expression.

```
"Data Source=" + @[User::varFileName] + ";Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;";
```

I received this error when evaluate the expression.

```
Expression cannot be evaluated.

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com:80/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%C2%AE%20Visual%20Studio%C2%AE&ProdVer=16.11.33927.289&EvtSrc=Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.TaskUIFramework.TaskUIFrameworkSR&EvtID=FailToEvaluateExpression&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Attempt to parse the expression ""Data Source=" + @[User::varFileName] + ";Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;";" failed. The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a parenthesis.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls)

------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is embedded quotes. And you're missing your final quote

```
"Data Source=" 
+ @[User::varFileName] 
+ ";Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;";
```

You'll see that there's a semicolon terminating the expression which isn't cricket for SSIS expression language.

The other challenge is there are double quotes in the string defining the Extended Properties.

To escape a double quote in the SSIS expression language, we need to precede it with a backslash `\` thus

```
"Data Source=" 
+ @[User::varFileName] 
+ ";Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;\";"
```

### Follow on question via comment

> in what circumstances I need to use the final quotes/ quotes in expression?

Every time. String concatenation in SSIS Expressions is either the literal string value e.g. "This is a literal string value" or an SSIS Variable of type String or a column of type DT_STR/DT_WSTR.

The concatenation operator is the plus symbol `+`

This is an example of concatenating two literal strings

```
"My username is " + "billinkc"
```

Result is

> My username is billinkc

This is an example of concatenating 1 literal string and 1 SSIS Variable

```
"This package was build on computer " + @[System::CreatorComputerName]
```

Result is

> This package was build on computer ERECH

This expression fails as we have a non-terminated string

```
"A" + "B
```

> Expression cannot be evaluated.

> Attempt to parse the expression ""A" + "B" failed.  The token """ at line number "1", character number "7" was not recognized. The expression cannot be parsed because it contains invalid elements at the location specified.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! I am new to SSIS, so still figuring out how to write expression. May I ask in what circumstances I need to use the final quotes/ quotes in expression?

Comment: @DataRookie Take a peep at the updated answer, does that make sense for your followup question?